# Socket.io - last connected user doesn't receive data

Tags: typescript, socket.io

I have a simple Node + Express application implementing real-time drawing on canvas using socket.io (ver. 1.7.2). 
I divide users between socket rooms, so multiple teams can draw indepentently. The problem is that last user that connects to given room doesn't receive any data. He can send data - he's drawings are transferred to others - but he cannot receive. Below is server-side socket code in Typescript :

```
import {User} from '../model';
export class DrawingSocket {
connectedUsers = [];
drawingConnection: any;

constructor(private socketIO: any) {
    this.socketIO.of('/sockets/drawing').on('connection', (con: any) => {
        this.drawingConnection = con;
        this.listen();
    });
    console.log("Drawing socket listening at /sockets/drawing/");
}

private listen(): void {
    this.drawingConnection.on("drawing", (data: any) => {
        console.log("[DRAWING] Room "+data.room);
        this.drawingConnection.to(data.room).emit("draw", data);
    });


    this.drawingConnection.on("clear", (data: any) => {
        console.log("[DRAWING] CLEAR for room "+data.room);
        this.drawingConnection.to(data.room).emit("clear", data);
    });

    this.drawingConnection.on("login", (user: any) => {
        this.drawingConnection.join(user.room);
        this.connectedUsers[user._id] = user;
        this.drawingConnection.to(user.room).emit("userlist", this.getSimpleUserList());
        this.drawingConnection.emit("userlist", this.getSimpleUserList());
        console.log("User " + user.name + " joined room " + user.room);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.socketIO.rooms));

    });

    this.drawingConnection.on("logout", (user: any) => {
        var room = this.connectedUsers[user._id].room;
        this.drawingConnection.to(room).emit("userlist", this.getSimpleUserList());
        this.drawingConnection.leave(room);
        console.log("User " + user.name + " disconnecting from room " + room + ".");
    });

    this.drawingConnection.on("disconnect", () => {
        //leave room and such
    });
}

private getSimpleUserList() {
    let list = this.connectedUsers.map((user) => user.login);
    return list;
}
}
```

When client connects I immediately send "login" event to server, and that works correctly - I can see the message on the server that he connects to correct room.

Please help, it's for my thesis and it's due next week :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer - the problem was that i saved the connection in from `.on('connection', (con:any)=>{this.drawingConnection=con}` Definitely shouldn't have done that, instead I passed the connection object to listen() function and used it instead of `this.drawingConnection` and it works correctly now.